# Changing cocoa bindings value programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have an `NSButton` in my preferences to interact with adding the application to the LoginItems. If the adding of the login item fails, I want to uncheck the box so the user doesn't get a false sense that it was added to the login items. However, after doing this, when I click the checkbox again, the bindings is not triggered.

[image]

```
- (void)addLoginItem:(BOOL)status
{
    NSURL *url = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:
                  @"Contents/Library/LoginItems/HelperApp.app"];

    // Registering helper app
    if (LSRegisterURL((__bridge CFURLRef)url, true) != noErr) {
        NSLog(@"LSRegisterURL failed!");
    }

    if (!SMLoginItemSetEnabled((__bridge CFStringRef)[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier], (status) ? true : false)) {
        NSLog(@"SMLoginItemSetEnabled failed!");
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"startAtLogin"];
        [self.startAtLogin setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:[self automaticStartup]] forKey:@"state"];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"startAtLogin"];
    }
}

- (void)setAutomaticStartup:(BOOL)state
{
    NSLog(@"Set automatic startup: %d", state);
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(addLoginItem:)]) {
        [self addLoginItem:state];
    }
}

- (BOOL)automaticStartup
{

    BOOL isEnabled  = NO;

    // the easy and sane method (SMJobCopyDictionary) can pose problems when sandboxed. -_-
    CFArrayRef cfJobDicts = SMCopyAllJobDictionaries(kSMDomainUserLaunchd);
    NSArray* jobDicts = CFBridgingRelease(cfJobDicts);

    if (jobDicts && [jobDicts count] > 0) {
        for (NSDictionary* job in jobDicts) {
            if ([[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier] isEqualToString:[job objectForKey:@"Label"]]) {
                isEnabled = [[job objectForKey:@"OnDemand"] boolValue];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Is Enabled: %d", isEnabled);
//    if (isEnabled != _enabled) {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"startupEnabled"];
        startupEnabled = isEnabled;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"startupEnabled"];
//    }

    return isEnabled;
}
```

I have my databinding for the checkbox bound to `self.automaticStartup`. If I remove the line `[self.startAtLogin setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:[self automaticStartup]] forKey:@"state"];` then the bindings work fine, but it doesn't uncheck, if the adding of the item fails.

How can I change this binding value programmatically so that every other binding event is not ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your explanation, your bound value is `automaticStartup`, but you are sending `willChangeValueForKey:` for `startAtLogin`.   In order for bindings to work correctly, you need to alert on the change to the bound variable at some point.   However, since you are in the midst of `setAutomaticStartup:` at the time, it's not really safe to do that here.

In this case, I would not use bindings to perform the change itself, I would consider the old-style `IBAction` mechanism and then set the checkbox value manually through an `IBOutlet` when you can confirm the status.